# CORS Laravel + Vue Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

Использую Vue Js для фронтенда и Laravel как api. Отправляю запросы к своему api при помощи axios, но у меня вылезает банальная проблема CORS политики.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:80/api/test' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https`

везде предлагают использовать `barryvdh/laravel-cors` для решения проблемы или писать middleware для того что бы в каждом запросе делать нужные заголовки. Есть ли более элегантное решение данной проблемы? Возможно вы знаете как в laravel это сделать грамотно. Спасибо всем кто прочитал и проявил внимание к моему вопросу.

Проблема не в запросе проблема именно в настройках cors для laravel т.к тестовые запросы на другие rest-сервисы у меня проходят успешно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась когда я изменил адрес запроса

было localhost:80/api/test

```js
axios.get('localhost:80/api/test')
     .then(function (response) {
           console.log(response);
      })
```

стало /api/test

```js
axios.get('/api/test')
     .then(function (response) {
           console.log(response);
      })
```

не ожидал я такого подвоха :) надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет